# How to Search a Paper by Citation

Tags: research-process, citations

I have a very simple question. I read a paper and need to take a look on one of the references. Say

5. R. Mansouri and S.U. Sexl. Gen. Rel. Grav. 8, 497 (1977).

Well, it was easy to search it if there were any title. How can I find the paper? I mean, its title or the journal it was published in. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of paper cites a reference without a title?  Yeesh. But I admire the detective work of @user2768, with two approaches to getting around it.

Comment: Actually I'll answer my own question. Google the citation as given and there are a zillion using just that form.  How helpful!

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

- Google "Gen. Rel. Grav." to discover that it abbreviates journal "
  General Relativity and Gravitation"
- Google the journal's title to discover http://link.springer.com/journal/volumesAndIssues/10714
- Look for issue 8 in 1977, don't find anything, assume 8 is a mistake (it later turned out to be the volume, which is redundant, because everything published in 1977 belongs to volume 8)
- Look for page 497 in 1977, find the result (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00762634), namely,

> Reza Mansouri & Roman U. Sexl (1997) A test theory of special relativity: I. Simultaneity and clock synchronization, General Relativity and Gravitation, Volume 8, Issue 7, pp 497–513.

In essence, I recognized that *Gen. Rel. Grav.* was most likely the journal's name. (The other possibility was *Sexl. Gen. Rel. Grav.*, but it seemed less likely, because *S.U. Sexl.* seemed likely to be the second author's name followed by a period.) Once I had found the journal, the year was most useful to me. I then guessed that 8 was the issue. This didn't turn up anything. (Later I discovered that 8 is the volumne.) Next, I guessed that 497 was a page reference, which guided be towards Issue 7. From their, I searched for (what I presumed was the first author's name) Mansouri, which gave me my result.

Comment: Thanks! I guessed I could find a search engine or something like that, for this purpose. But this seems a good and routine way.

Answer (score 3):

Recognize that *R. Mansouri* is the first author's name and that *1977* is the year of publication, and search Google Scholar using that information, i.e., visit https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=author%3AR.+Mansouri&as_ylo=1977&as_yhi=1977. From those results, deduce that

> Reza Mansouri & Roman U. Sexl (1977) *A test theory of special relativity: I. Simultaneity and clock synchronization*, General Relativity and Gravitation, Volume 8, Issue 7, pp 497–513

is the correct result, because it is the only result that starts on page 497.

Comment: Did you mean to edit your original answer or add a comment? Please don't write a duplicate answer.

Comment: I've given two distinct answers. My first answer (http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/87690/22768) is based upon what I did. The second (http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/87694/22768) builds upon the OP's comment (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87689/how-to-search-a-paper-by-citation/87694?noredirect=1#comment221786_87690) that a search engine could be used. My answers use different tools: the first uses Google [search], the second uses Google Scholar. So, I think the distinction should be clear.

Comment: Feed the two last names into Google Scholar and it's the first hit.